# Eclipse Java JNI error occures

Tags: java, eclipse

I just started with programming Java.
I want to use Eclipse. I already installed latest JRE 8 and JDK. But when I want to run my `"Hello World"` problem I get the following error:

"Error: A JNI error has occured, please check your installation and try again."
After that a new error window appears:
"A Java Exception has occured."

Beside the console gives me following details:

```
    `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [LString;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: String
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more`
```

What installation do I have to check? Thank you!

Comment: Check the Installed runtime in eclipse whether you have mapped your java8 or not?

Comment: Can you show the code

Comment: My code is:

`
public class Application {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  System.out.println("Hello world!");

 }

}
``

Comment: Are you using any external (native) libraries? The error message is odd. If this class is to be resolved from JNI, it should be `[Ljava/lang/String;`. I'd consider re-installing the JDK and Eclipse.